# Maui project for Android: type androidx.collection.ArrayMapKt is defined multiple times

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0

I have a `MAUI` project and it was working. After the installation of the update of Visual Studio, I tried to build the project and now I get this error:

> JAVA0000 Error in C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class:
> Type androidx.collection.ArrayMapKt is defined multiple times: C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class, C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx\1.2.0.9\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class
> Compilation failed
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar
> androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:126)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.main(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:5)
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class
> at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_8.1.56.java:0)
> at com.android.tools.r8.M.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:5)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:81)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:32)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:31)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.b(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:2)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:26)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:13)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:24)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:113)
> ... 1 more
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type androidx.collection.ArrayMapKt is defined multiple times: C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class, C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx\1.2.0.9\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:21)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:26)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:44)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:10)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2056)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:6)
> at com.android.tools.r8.graph.b4$a.e(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:7)
> at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:58)
> at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:9)
> at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:8)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:29)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:17)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.c(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:1)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:28)
> ... 6 more

[image]

I have done a file search and I can't find any reference to the `ArrayMapKt`. The application is running without issue with Windows. All the NuGet packages are updated to the latest version and the framework is NET8.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: The exception includes the two definition of `androidx.collection.ArrayMapKt`: 

`C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class` and ` C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx\1.2.0.9\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class`

You will have to make sure that you only depend on one version of `xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm`.

Answer (score 3):

Add `Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.Ktx` to your nuget packages.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18665#issuecomment-1806895333

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with NuGet package BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui 8.0.0.1 and couldn't find the issue at all no matter what I searched google for.

In the end I installed version 8.0.0.0 of the same package and the error disappeared.

Hope this might help.